# Am I not properly initializing my list? Trying to append to an empty list only returns last value - R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, append

Here the `maxFlowFordFulkerson()` returns a value for maximum flow, which is `28` when I use the `arcs` matrix as the argument.  What I need to do however, is to multiply the `capacity` column in arcs by the constant `k` to see how the maximum flow is affected by increases in capacity and to store these values in the matrix `sensitivity`.  I've set up `tempArcs` to be a temporary version of the matrix `arcs` with the capacities multiplied by `k[i]`.

My problem is that the only values that get saved into flows are those of the last iteration. I thought I had properly initialized my lists, so why is this not giving me different values?

```
library(optrees)

nodes = c(1:8)

from = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7)
to = c(2,3,4,5,4,6,7,3,5,7,2,6,8,5,7,8,6,8)
capacity = c(20,15,10,15,13,15,10,13,10,12,15,7,10,7,8,8,8,10)
arcs = cbind(from, to, capacity)

k = c(1:10)
flows = c()
for (i in seq_along(k))
  tempArcs = cbind(arcs[,-3], arcs[,3]*k[i])
  max = maxFlowFordFulkerson(nodes, tempArcs)
  flows = append(flows, max$max.flow)

sensitivity = cbind(k, flows)
sensitivity

       k flows
 [1,]  1   280
 [2,]  2   280
 [3,]  3   280
 [4,]  4   280
 [5,]  5   280
 [6,]  6   280
 [7,]  7   280
 [8,]  8   280
 [9,]  9   280
[10,] 10   280
```

Comment: Missing `{}` in the `for` loop. In R `for` loop should be `for(){...}`

Comment: I just removed my comment because I noticed I had changed something in my original code that was affecting the output.  Thank you this solved my problem.  

I actually did not know that `{}` served a purpose besides visually breaking up pieces of code. @A.Suliman